# How to enumerate through dictionary in Objective-C in the order in which they were defined

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, enumeration

Is it possible to enumerate NSDictionary in the order in which the key-value is defined?

Comment: Nope but have look at e.g. https://github.com/Marxon13/NSOrderedDictionary

Comment: Ugh. Bad practice to create your own class using the NS prefix. Use your own SEPARATE prefix so it's clear it's not part of the Cocoa frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do this. You'll have to store the order as a property of the added objects or use NSNumber as the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. From the documentation:

> allKeys Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
>
> - (NSArray *)allKeys Return Value A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> Discussion The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do this is by creating an array of keys first. 
Then use that array, iterating over it to create the dictionary. 
Dictionaries do not have any inherent concept of order.